# use angular.js directives in different applications?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that I want to use in various places.

```
var app1 = angular.module("App1"...);
app1.directive('ngFoo' ...   );
```

other Webpage:

```
var app2 = angular.module("App2"...);
app2.directive('ngFoo'  ...   );
```

How can I add the code of the directive in a practical way in different pages? 
What is there best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a **module pattern**, that creates the ability to reuse code easily. If the directive is the same for app1 and app2 i suggest to create your own module for the directive:

```
angular.module('myDirectiveModule', []).directive('ngFoo', ...);
```

Then, if you want to use the directive in `app1` you include it as dependency of your app1 module:

```
angular.module('app1', ['myDirectiveModule']);
```

You can then just go ahead and use the directive in app1. The same is true, if you want to use the directive in app2:

```
angular.module('app2', ['myDirectiveModule']);
```

So the directive becomes it's own reusable module.